# Nginx rules for upper/lower case locations

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

So, here’s my situation.  I have a site that has some custom logic coming from a separate upstream application.  I have this working right now with no problems, though my straight forward solution is a little verbose.  I will soon be adding more of these custom locations, as well as adding the ability to access these locations in uppercase as well as lower.  My solution will work, but the list of locations will soon become unwieldy and I’d like to re-think my solution.

So, let’s assume my upstream is called “myupstream” and is defined already in the file.  My custom locations will be one, two, three, and four. (real locations names changed for their own protection).

So these urls:

http://mysite/one
http://mysite/two
http://mysite/three
http://mysite/four

And in my nginx.conf:

```
    location /one {
            log_request_speed_filter on;
            log_request_speed_filter_timeout 1000;
            proxy_pass   http://myupstream/one;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
    location /two {
            log_request_speed_filter on;
            log_request_speed_filter_timeout 1000;
            proxy_pass   http://myupstream/two;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
…
etc.
```

All of the locations are identical besides the name of the location.

Now, the number of the locations is a few right now, but may grow to be a few dozen.  And then, add the ability to visit the locations in uppercase as well as lower case.  So:

http://mysite/one
http://mysite/ONE
http://mysite/two
http://mysite/TWO
etc…

If I have 20 locations, using my current strategy I’d be creating 40 different location blocks inside my nginx.conf.  So, I was looking for a way that was a little more dynamic.  Some thing like:

```
    location /(one|two|three) {
            log_request_speed_filter on;
            log_request_speed_filter_timeout 1000;
            proxy_pass   http://myupstream/$1;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
```

OF course, I’d like it to ONLY work for specific entries, so a wide open rule would not work.  Plus, I’d like to detect uppercase as well, but when calling the upstream it would need to be lowercase.  For example:

```
    location /ONE {
            log_request_speed_filter on;
            log_request_speed_filter_timeout 1000;
            proxy_pass   http://myupstream/one;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
```

So question 1:

Is there a better way to do this in nginx?  How?

Question 2:

Which way is more resource/process efficient?

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the case-insensitive [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) matching:

```
location ~* /(one|two|three) {
  log_request_speed_filter on;
  log_request_speed_filter_timeout 1000;
  proxy_pass   http://myupstream/$1;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

There is another approach - using templates:

**`/etc/nginx/host.tmpl`**

```
log_request_speed_filter on;
log_request_speed_filter_timeout 1000;
proxy_pass   http://myupstream/$host_loc;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

**`/etc/nginx/vhost.d/somehost.conf`**

```
location /one {
  set $host_loc "one";
  include host.impl;
}
```

Note, Nginx doesn't support variables in the location URI.

I'd suggest you to benchmark different configurations in order to choose the most efficient ones.

*EDIT*

If you want to pass `/FOUR` requests to `http://myupstream/four` as well as 
`/FoUr` requests to `http://myupstream/four` etc., then you should use a
module such as the [Perl module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html), because Nginx currently hasn't built-in variables for a lowercase version of URI, or built-in functions to convert the location URI to lowercase.

**`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`**

```
http {
  perl_set $uri_lc 'sub { return lc shift->uri; }';
}
```

In the subroutine, we:

- fetch the [request object](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html#methods) with `shift`;
- get the current URI from the request object: `shift->uri`;
- pass the URI to [`lc` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html) and return the result

The result is assigned to `$uri_lc` Nginx variable.

**`/etc/nginx/vhost.d/somehost.conf`**

```
location ~* ^/(one|two|three)$ {
  log_request_speed_filter on;
  log_request_speed_filter_timeout 1000;
  proxy_pass   http://myupstream$uri_lc;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}
```

The markers `^`(start) and `$`(end) are important.

Comment: In the above example, if someone calls http://example.com/FOUR, will the value being passed to the upstream be "four" or "FOUR"?  I need it to be "four".

Comment: Thanks!  This was exactly what I needed.